# Error when running java bat file

Tags: java, utf-8, jvm

When i am starting my bat file:

```
@echo off
title x
:start
echo.
java -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms64m -Xmx64m -Xbootclasspath/p:../libs/l2ft.jar -    cp config/xml;../libs/*; l2ft.loginserver.AuthServer
if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto restart
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
goto end
:restart
echo Restarted ...
goto start
:error
echo Terminated abnormaly ...
:end
echo Terminated ...
```

I am getting strange error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: UTF-8
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.forOutputStreamWriter(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried to reinstall java jdk, i have got default encoding in bat file already: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, so i dont know whats the solution for the problem.

Comment: why do you need to set the bootclasspath ? you only need to set the classpath with -cp

Comment: oh i am not sure actually, thats just the code i am running. I am sure the bat file itself and the jar files hidding behind it are working just fine, i have tested them on another pc. Something with the pc is wrong, i just dont know how to solve it.

Comment: Is it possible that your hyphen was replaced with an en-dash?

Comment: our files are just the same. Just copyed text from my friend's bat file to mine, error still appears :(

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. In the jar that contained AuthServer, were a lot of russian characters that UTF-8 doesnt support. After removing each of those characters and recompiling, problem was gone. Jar file of my friend also contained those characters, but it was working without a problems. I dont know how, but thats not important now, since the problem is gone.

Comment: "lot of russian characters that UTF-8 doesnt support" - I'm not sure that's possible unless Unicode.org have missed them! It actually sounds like your files were not UTF-8 encoded but your friends files were.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Java doesn't support UTF-8, which is really strange, because every Java should support it according to the [documentation of the Charset class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

Try to run this code to make sure that UTF-8 is really not supported.

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class TestCharset {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

If UTF-8 is not supported, it should throw an exception.

You may also try it with `UTF8` instead of `UTF-8` just in case your use an incorrect hyphen character. `UTF-8` is correct according to the specs, but `UTF8` works on my machine as well.

Comment: i am not getting exception, UTF-8 is a result.

Comment: That's really strange, because you are getting exception from the very same method - `Charset.forName`. The only reason I can think of is that you use an incorrect hyphen character. Please try it with `UTF8` or delete the hyphen in `UTF-8` and type it in again to make sure it is the correct character.

Comment: In my TestCharset class, i am getting UTF-8 message, even if i have for "UTF8" string in Charset.forName() method. In bat file, i am getting error while using UTF-8 or UTF8. There is no difference between those 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your p:../libs/l2ft.jar, that is not a right path. Try to replace your current line with this:

```
java -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms64m -Xmx64m -cp p:../libs/l2ft.jar;config/xml;../libs/* l2ft.loginserver.AuthServer
```

just be sure to replace "p:../libs/l2ft.jar" with a proper path where the l2ft.jar resides.

Comment: getting this error now: Starting LoginServer.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file l2ft/loginserver/AuthServer

Comment: your program is now launched. try to read this http://www.coderanch.com/t/322531/java/java/Illegal-UTF-string-constant-pool

Comment: I guess there is a missmatch between your class files compiled level and the jvm that is running your classes. What version of jdk did you use to compile? What is the version of the jvm that is now running your compliled classes?

Comment: the files were compiled on my pc. I am using jdk7, not sure what you mean by version of jvm

Comment: The version of the jvm running your program and that is creating your problem. The jvm is that runs java programs, the jdk is the set of tools to build java application, like the compiler. Be sure that you are using your jdk7 in your machine to compile (and no another instalation of jdk in your machine). And in the server or the other pc where you are having problem you have to be sure that you have jvm7. try to do "java -version" in the command line and see what it prints.

Comment: cmd prints that java version is 1.7, thats the only version i have installed in the pc. I reinstalled it many times just to fix that problem but nothing :(

Comment: Okay, apparently you have corrupted class files. Unless you can give us something we can reproduce I think that no one will be able to help you in this

Comment: so what was the solution ? what was the real problem ? Please at least answer your question. Otherwise the whole thing here is useless

Comment: i wrote :P I made answer to my own question :) I have it above this answer :)